# Why does this sum not converge in Python

Tags: python, numpy, sum

The following function peval2 gives a saturation curve converging to 1 which is correct e.g. in Maple. Python however calculates wrong sum values. Can anyone give me a hint what i'm doing wrong?

```
from numpy import *
from scipy.optimize import leastsq
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def peval2(x, p):
    b,c = p
    err = 0 * x
    for ii in range(0,30):
        for jj in range(0,30):
            for kk in range(0,30):
                err += exp(-1.0*x*pi**2.0*(b*(((2.0*ii+1.0)/75.0)**2+((2.0*jj+1)/75.0))**2+c*((2.0*kk+1)/2.0)**2.0))/((2.0*ii+1)*(2.0*jj+1)*(2.0*kk+1))**2.0
    print err
    return 1.0-((8.0/pi**2)**3*err)

rr = linspace(0,4000,100)

plt.plot(rr,peval2(rr,[5e-7,2e-7]))

plt.show()
```

Comment: Here's a thought: precedence rules for operators might not be the same in Python and Maple.

Comment: Rounding errors, maybe?

Comment: How are we supposed to know if you've written the correct code?  Tell us what it's supposed to do, or better yet, show us the correct Maple code.

Comment: I've put everything in brackets and checked multiple times for typos. I don't know why the order of operators should differ between Maple and Python.

Comment: This is my working Maple Code. It's just a function definition of a saturation curve. massuptake(D1,D2,D3,time):=1- (8/(Pi^(2)))^(3) evalf(Sum(evalf(Sum(Sum((exp(-(D1*((2* ii+1)/(75))^(2)+D2*((2* jj+1)/(75))^(2)+D3*((2* kk+1)/(4))^(2))*Pi^(2)*time))/((2*ii+1)^(2)*(2*jj+1)^(2)*(2* kk+1)^(2)),ii=0..30),jj=0..30)),kk=0..30)):  ;

massuptake2(time):=massuptake(0.001,0.001,0.002,time):

massuptake3(D1,D2,time):=massuptake(D1,D1,D2,time):

plot(('massuptake2')(time), time = 0 .. 3000, numpoints = 20);

Comment: I'd recommend breaking the big calculation down into intermediate values and printing them in both Maple and Python to see how and when the overall calculation is differing.

Comment: from __ future __ import division didn't help, poop.

Answer (score 2):

Are you use the same parameters as Maple code? I changed the parameters as:

```
plt.plot(rr,peval2(rr,[0.001, 0.002]))
```

the result:

[image]